# Apps For Android Like JsFiddle

Tags: android, offline, html-editor

I would like names for apps for Android that work like JsFiddle but locally. Basically, an editor where I can write HTML, CSS and JS and see the changes right there. No need to save files or anything. Because I might be offline with my pad. So any suggestion regarding this is welcome.

Comment: So basically a WYSIWYG HTML editor? If so, you might wish to check my list of [Text editors for developers](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_office#group_105).

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for the comment. But I meant more like code editor where I can write code with syntax highlighting and then I can see the preview of the HTML, JS and CSS.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Syntax highlighting, text completion, and the likes are definitely present in those ones. Didn't check for the preview features, as I'd say those should be even more "essential" than code-completion ;)

Comment: anWriter free is the best i found yet. It has autocompletion and highlights and allows previews. I use it for simple exercises.

Answer (score 2):

http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/

[image: kodeweave a jsfiddle alternative for android]

kodeWeave is a realtime HTML, CSS, Javascript and Markdown coding playground. Similar to JSFiddle and JSBin, but kodeWeave was made to work offline.

kodeWeave is similar to jsfiddle, jsbin, dabblet, liveweave, codepen and tinkerbin, but allows you to export your web app as a desktop and/or chrome application or extension (this functionality is slowly being ported to Android)

You can save your weave to the cloud and share it with your friends both on the web app and in the Android application.

In addition kodeWeave comes with a built in color picker and numeric slider, along with support for jade, coffeescript and stylus preprocessors.

So currently if you're looking for a jsFiddle alternative for Android. This one is for you!

Answer (score 1):

[Webmaster Lite HTML Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.welant.webmaster.DEMO) does this but only the paid version will let you preview it. It has syntax highlighting for css, javascript, html etc although you do need to save code locally prior to doing a preview. Options include dark or light interface, line numbers, a search/replace function (which is a bit buggy)  and setting the file type, with the default being UTF-8. It's very usable on small screens and excellent on a tablet.

[image: Small screen view]

To view the code you have written without the paid version you can launch a web browser when offline and enter the path, eg as `file://storage/emulated/0/coding/test.html` if it is using as folder called coding.  Boat Browser will allow you to double-click the file and launch without typing the path.

Also good is **TurboEditor (Text Editor)** by Maskyn, pretty much the same features but the newer versions now include ads in the free version. There is only a tiny ad box in Webmaster Lite so usually I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try JSitor.com, JSitor provides both Web and Mobile Apps. It simple to use and very straight forward.

[JSitor.com](https://jsitor.com)

[image]

**JSitor Apps -**

iOS - https://apps.apple.com/us/app/jsitor/id1455784773

Android - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ashvin777.apps.jsitor
[image]